# Ignoring Quotes in Insert String C#, SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-insert

I can't insert `NULL` value into a `Date` column in my database because I need to use a string variable.

Insert statement:

```
string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO PersonelListesi (id, ssk_tarih) VALUES(1,'" + sskTarihi + "')";
```

Working variable example:

```
string sskTarihi = "20201212";
```

Incorrect variable examples (which I have tried):

```
sskTarihi = "NULL";
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

```
sskTarihi = "'NULL'";
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'

```
sskTarihi = "\"'NULL'\"";
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'

```
sskTarihi = "\"NULL\"";
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

```
sskTarihi = "\'NULL\'";
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'

```
sskTarihi = "\"\'NULL\'\"";
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'

I hope you got what i mean and what i need. I appreciate the help. Thanks for your answers in advance. :)

Comment: Don't bother escaping quotes; simply [use parameters](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/). For `NULL`, specify parameter value `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: string concatenation should be avoided against the statements being vulnerable to injection.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan and Dan, thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others recommended use parameters as shown below where the method resides in a class.

```
public static void InsertRow(int id, string ssk_tarih)
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection {ConnectionString = "TODO"})
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand {Connection = cn})
        {

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PersonelListesi (id, ssk_tarih) VALUES(@id,@ssk_tarih)";


            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ssk_tarih))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ssk_tarih", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ssk_tarih", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ssk_tarih;
            }

            cn.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = id;` - that should **probably** be `SqlDbType.Int` rather than date time....

Comment: @marc_s that's what I get when doing a copy-n-paste, thanks for pointing this out.